# Detect Device Type To Speed Up Website

Tags: css, stylesheet, device, user-agent

I would like to find a way to detect device type of visitors in order to load only the relevant stylesheet. ( Either desktop or mobile css )
Indeed, the CSS is render blocking, so, I would like to avoid 2 .CSS to be loaded every time ( style.css AND mobile.css )
Maybe there is another way to do it? 
Regards,

Comment: Have you tried Media Queries?

Comment: You're better off searching Google for tutorials. Your question is way too broad, therefore off topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

`<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />`

Above will apply css only for device with screen with between 701px and 900px.

You can use media queries and set breakpoints. Refer below link for more information.

https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/